# How to reset ObjectInputStream objects graph cache to avoid memory bloat

Tags: java, serialization

When loading huge files with ObjectInputStream, all read objects are buffered by stream for object graph resolving.
This cause huge memory overhead which isn't needed in my case (all objects read are interdependent).
Is there an equivalent to the reset() method of ObjectOutputStream which reset this buffer?

Code example:

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
         BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
         ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(bufferedInputStream)) {
  while (object = objectInputStream.readObject()) {
    System.Out.println(object.toString());
  }
}
```

- There is actually a reset method on the class but it does a complete different thing.
- See [Java APIs which cause memory bloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281549/memory-leak-traps-in-the-java-standard-api)

Comment: can you show us your codes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's up to the sender to decide when to break the integrity of sent object graphs, by calling `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`. Not the receiver.

NB your code doesn't compile, and wouldn't be valid if it did:

```
while (object = objectInputStream.readObject()) {
}
```

This should be

```
try {
    while (true) {
        object = objectInputStream.readObject();
        // ...
    }
}
catch (EOFException exc) {
    // end of stream
}
```

There is a misconception abroad that `readObject()` returns `null` at end of stream. It doesn't. It throws `EOFException`. It can return `null` any time you wrote a `null`.

Comment: so this means you should never use ObjectInputStream.reset()  ?

Comment: @MarkY. `ObjectInputStream.reset()` is inherited from [`InputStream.reset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset--), which does nothing except throw an `IOException`, so you certainly shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm it seems you need to use some sort of lazy loading techniques where you only load necessairy components of the object graph, not everything.

Comment: In other words you've never heard of `ObjectOutputStream.reset()`.